# Java: Why are my object arrays being created & having their references passed so slowly?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, enums

I'm trying to figure out if there is something wrong with the way I'm creating Object arrays in my code, or if handling Object arrays in Java is more expensive than I originally thought it was.

I have a simple enum class called `ElementaryTransitionTerm`, consisting of ony two primitive member variables. A method in another class creates an array consisting of a combination of this Enum's constants (with the possible length of the array never exceeding 3).

The problem is that in total, the program spends (on average) **13ms** inside said method, though it is **called only 8 times**. I have no idea why.

Running times were calculated 2 ways:

1. Surrounding the call to the method by System.nanoTime() calls.
2. Surrounding each array creation statement inside the method by
   System.nanoTime() calls and summing them up

Here is the **ElementaryTransitionTerm** enum class:

```
public enum ElementaryTransitionTerm 
{
    MATCH(1, 0), INSERTION(0, 1), SUBSTITUTION(1, 1), DELETION(0, 0), FAILURE(0, 0);

    private final int I_OFFSET;
    private final int E_OFFSET;


    private ElementaryTransitionTerm(int iOffset, int eOffset)
    {
        I_OFFSET = iOffset;
        E_OFFSET = eOffset;

    }
}
```

Here is the method in question, **createTransitionTerms** (as well as the declaration of the enum type used as a parameter):

```
//'E' and 'I' are both private int fields in the parent class.

private enum RelevantSubwordHitIndexType { FIRST_INDEX, TRAILING_INDEX, NO_INDEX };

/**
 * Creates an array of ElementaryTransitionTerm constants.

 * @param hitIndexType     a RelevantSubwordHitIndexType enum constant
 */
private ElementaryTransitionTerm[] createTransitionTerms(RelevantSubwordHitIndexType hitIndexType)
{
    //Simple getter method chained in to String.length() call
    int onePastFinalBoundary = parentAutomaton.getAutomatonString().length(); 

    if(E < parentAutomaton.getMaxEditDistance())   //Simple getter method retrieving an int
    {
        if(I < onePastFinalBoundary - 1)           
        {
            switch(hitIndexType)
            {
                case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                case TRAILING_INDEX:    return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.DELETION};
                default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION};
            }
        }
        else if(I == onePastFinalBoundary - 1)     
        {
            switch(hitIndexType)
            {
                case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION};
            }
        }
        else                            return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION};     
    else                                            
    {
        if(I < onePastFinalBoundary)                
        {
            switch(hitIndexType)
            {
                case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.FAILURE};
            }
        }
        else                            return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.FAILURE};
    }
}
```

The method essentially evaluates a small set of conditionals in order to create a small array. However, the total execution time of 8 runs of this method does not reflect that.

I've even gone so far as to declare the to-be-returned arrays as `public final` arrays in ElementaryTransitionTerm, and replace the creation statements in the above methods with references to these arrays, but it has absolutely no effect on the code's running time.

I've written code that does more in less time. So I'm curious as to why this method is behaving like this. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**:

After further testing, i've discovered a two things:

1. Testing the method in isolation yields expected (i.e
   sub-millisecond) results.
2. Testing  the method within the program, it seems as though whichever
   array creation statement is executed on the first call to the
   function is essentially responsible for the times i'm seeing. All
   subsequent calls complete in sub-millisecond times.

Concerning #2: What is the reason for this, and how can I go about rectifying it?

Comment: Where are you getting your timing information from?

Comment: @Jeffrey   Updated original post with that info :)

Comment: This is probably a microbenchmarking issue. You should really only worry about performance when your application becomes *noticeably* slower (13 ms is hardly noticeable).

Comment: The reason that performance is critical is that this this is for one run of the program on a single String. In real-world usage, the program will be run on thousands of Strings in succession.

Comment: Have you testing it on a thousand strings? Most computers are very inaccurate when measuring times of anything less than 20-40ms. You can't profile your method based on only 8 method calls...

Comment: @Dunes: I haven't tested it with that many Strings yet. You present a valid point. I think I have narrowed down the problem (please see the new edit at the bottom of the original post). Do you have any thoughts on those findings?

Comment: Could be any number of things. Could be that method is interupted by garbage collection, could be that the JVM decides to optimise the code and suspends execution whilst it performs the optimisation. Performance wise never expected the JVM to perform exactly the same way over a few method calls each and every time. To get semi-reasonable performance metrics you need to run a test that will last at least several seconds.

Comment: @Dunes: It turns out you were correct. The benchmark was to small to accurately measure the performance of the method. If you would be so kind as to submit your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 2):

Ran your code, I get 25-30 ms time for one million calls to that method. Running ona Sony Vaio Z, i5, 4 GB Ram, Win 7 64 but, JDK 6 64 bit.

Here's the actual code I tried:

```
    private ElementaryTransitionTerm[] createTransitionTerms(RelevantSubwordHitIndexType hitIndexType) {
            //Simple getter method chained in to String.length() call
            int onePastFinalBoundary = "A".length(); 

//Here I also tried if(1 < 2) to change the if/else execution path, same run time for each.
            if(3 < 2)    {
                if(1 < 2) {
                    switch(hitIndexType) {
                        case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                        case TRAILING_INDEX:    return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.DELETION};
                        default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION};
                    }
                } else if(1 == 1) {
                    switch(hitIndexType) {
                        case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                        default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION, ElementaryTransitionTerm.SUBSTITUTION};
                    }
                }
                else {                     
                    return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION};
                }
            } else  {
                if(1 < 2) {
                    switch(hitIndexType) {
                        case FIRST_INDEX:       return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.MATCH};
                        default:                return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.FAILURE};
                    }
                } else {
                    return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] {ElementaryTransitionTerm.FAILURE};
                }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            T1 t = new T1();
            long st = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i = 0 ; i<1000000; i++) {
                t.createTransitionTerms(RelevantSubwordHitIndexType.FIRST_INDEX);
            }
            long et = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(et-st);
        }
```

Can you tell us on what Hardware, OS, JDK version were you testing?

Comment: I'm running on a 2.0 GHz Core 2 Duo, 2 GB ram, Vista, using JDK7. I also ran the method in isolation and it is giving me expected (i.e sub-millisecond) results. Why is the method giving me problems in the actual program?

Answer (score 2):

To complete Shivan's answer, I have run a test with randomly generated input (one million time) and I get results between 40 and 50ms.

Here is the the random generation part :

```
public MyTest() {
    Random r = new Random();

    parentAutomaton = new ParentAutomaton();
    parentAutomaton.maxEditDistance = r.nextInt(255);
    parentAutomaton.automatonStringLen = r.nextInt(255);
    E = r.nextInt(255);
    I = r.nextInt(255);
    relevantSubwordHitIndexType = RelevantSubwordHitIndexType.values()[r.nextInt(3)];

}
```

and the execution method :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    List<MyTest> l = new ArrayList<MyTest>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
         l.add(new MyTest());
    }

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (MyTest t:l) {
        t.createTransitionTerms(t.relevantSubwordHitIndexType);
    }

    double dur_nano = System.nanoTime() - start;
    double dur_mili = dur_nano / 1000000.0;
    System.out.println("Finished in : " + dur_mili);

}
```

My OS is `Ubuntu 12.04` and my CPU is an `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T7250`  @ 2.00GHz with 2GB ram. I ran it with Java 1.6.0_24.

Let me know if you want the full source code.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth an experiment to try the following ideas:

1. Pre-create some of the arrays such as `return new ElementaryTransitionTerm[] { ElementaryTransitionTerm.INSERTION };` and keep them as `private static` values.
2. Reorder your cases and conditions so if there is one branch that is much more commonly executed than the others, then put that first somehow.

Comment: 1. Already did something similar, see the end of the original post. 2. The cases are already ordered in such a way.

Comment: -1 1. static fields??? better hope there's only one thread calling it 2. won't help - the execution of these tests would be measured in nanosecond - reordering will do jack squat

Comment: @Bohemian -- Whaaat?? Why would the number of threads matter? They would just be immutable constants. Sorry, it is perfectly thread-safe though. 2. That depends on hardware, but if he's trying to shave off a couple ms for some reason, then it's worth an experiment, especially if certain code paths are very rarely used.